# How to provide an STL container to a class method for lazy evaluation?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I'm trying to implement a parallel data gathering with consequent single-task data processing. Parallel task would gather data into a number of vectors then pass the collected containers into a single-task processing class. Once all the gatherers complete the data gathering, the processing stage would commence.

However, I'm confused at how to implement a processing class members that would hold the gathered data. I cannot make them references to vectors because references should be initialized at the processing object initialization time. I probably cannot make them pointers to vectors because pointer fiddling is discouareged. I also cannot make them another bunch of vectors to avoid the unnecessary data copying during the assignment operations.

How should I design the internals of the processing class to bypass those limitations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in your question - "...gather data into a number of vectors then pass the collected containers..."

You can make your internal data structures `std::vector` and pass the outside data using [move](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) and  [swap](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/swap2) them with the internal vectors:

```
class foo
{
    public:
        void set_vector(std::vector<int>&& vector)
        {
            std::swap(internal_vector, vector);
        }

        void alternative_set_vector(std::vector<int>& vector)
        {
            std::swap(internal_vector, vector);
        }

    private:
        std::vector<int> internal_vector;
};

void use_foo()
{
    foo some_foo;
    {
        std::vector<int> outside_vector;//fill outside_vector with your data
        some_foo.set_vector(std::move(outside_vector));
    }
    {
        std::vector<int> outside_vector;//fill outside_vector with your data
        some_foo.alternative_set_vector(outside_vector);
    }
}
```

The version with `alternative_set_vector` works fine, but it's not obvious for the calling code that the vector will be "filled" with some "random" values after the call.

Comment: There are assigment operators inside the `std::swap` and `std::move` is in C++11

Comment: @mbaitoff std::swap for vectors has constant time complexity - std::move doesn't do any assignment - it's just a cast. Please check the links inside the answer

Comment: yes, you're right about the `std::swap`. However, that would result in an original vector of data becoming empty, right? Is there a way for the data to remain in the original vector, to be used in another processing class, assuming that the processing doesn't alter the data?

Comment: You can grab the data from the processing class as you put it there. But to be honest I won't recommend this. If you really have SHARED data, why don't you just use a shared_ptr? It looks like you really share the data!